# Print asterisk arrow using only While loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, python-3.6

I am trying to create an arrow out of asterisk's, where the amount of columns is entered by the user. Yes, I do know how to use for loops to accomplish this:

```
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))
while columns <= 0:
    print ("Invalid entry, try again!")
    columns = int(input("How many columns? "))
x = 1

for x in range(1, columns):
    for x in range(x):
        print(" ", end="")
    print("*")

for x in range(columns,0,-1): 
    for x in range(x):
        print(" ", end="")
    print("*")

#output looks like

"""
How many columns? 3
*
 *
  *
 *
*
"""
```

However my question is, how would I accomplish the same outcome using only while loops?

Thanks

Edit: I was going to post what I had thus far in trying to work it out myself, but it is now of no use!
Thank you all for your efficient varying answers! Much appreciated!

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))


while columns <= 0:
    print ("Invalid entry, try again!")
    columns = int(input("How many columns? "))

x = 1
while x < columns:
    y = 0
    while y < x:
        print(" ", end="")
        y += 1
    print("*")
    x += 1


x = columns
while x > 0:
    y = 0
    while y < x:
        print(" ", end="")
        y += 1
    print("*")
    x -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a version that doesn't loop using indexing.

```
def print_arrow(n):
    a = '*'.ljust(n + 1)
    while a[-1] != '*':
        print(a)
        a = a[-1] + a[:-1]
    a = a[1:]
    while a[0] != '*':
        a = a[1:] + a[0]
        print(a)

# Test    
print_arrow(4)
```

**output**

```
*    
 *   
  *  
   * 
  * 
 *  
*
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's better to use functions. And easier if you know that `character*number` returns that `character` concatenated `number` times.

Example:

```
'*'*10
```

returns

```
'**********'
```

So your program using whiles would follow the same logic.

```
def print_arrow(k):
    i = 0
    while(i < k-1):
        print(i*' ' + '*')
        i +=1 

    while(i >= 0):
        print(i*' ' + '*')
        i -= 1
```

The first while prints the upper part, the last one uses the fact that `i = k-1`, so just do same in the reversed order.

Example:

```
print_arrow(3)
```

returns

```
*
 *
  *
 *
*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input( ))
n1 = n//2 + 1
i = 1
while i <= n1:
    space = 1
    while space <= i - 1:
        print(" ",end="")
        space += 1
    j = 1
    p = "*"
    while j <= i:
        if j == i:
            print(p,end="")
        else:
            print("* ",end="")
        j += 1
    print()
    i += 1
i = n - n1
while i >= 1:
    space = 1
    while space <= i - 1:
        print(" ",end="")
        space += 1
    j = 1
    p = "*"
    while j <= i:
        if j == i:
            print(p,end="")
        else:
            print("* ",end="")
        j += 1
    print()
    i -= 1
```

**Arrow pattern of asterisk**
*-Remember the n value here is always odd*

for n = 5
output will be

Comment: You did not post your output, but running your code produces a different kind of arrow than the OP wanted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32078766)